# A Question on the properties of probability mass functions of discrete random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Assuming There are two discrete random variables X and Y that are identically distributed.

$X$ takes on values $x_1, x_2, ... , x_m$ and Y takes on value $y_1, ..., y_n$. $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ are probability mass functions of $x$ and $y$, respectivly and $p(x,y)$ is the joint distribution of $x$ and $y$.
Let $Z$ be a discrete random variable and $Z = X+Y$.

Assuming  $z_m = x_i+y_j$, is it correct to write $p(Z=z_m,Y=y_j) = p(X=x_i,Y=y_j)$? or $p(Z=z_m|X=x_i) = p(Y=y_j|X=x_i)$ ?

I assumed the above expression are correct. But I don't know if there is a formal proof for that. 
Can any one help to confirm this please? Thanks.

Comment: what means $p(X)$ if $X$ is a random variable?

Comment: Indeed, so many abuses of notation... Ironically, getting rid of these might be all it takes the OP to get a full answer.

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for your comment. p(X) is probablity distribution of X.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Did. You meant my question does not make sense or something is not correct?

Comment: I said (not "meant") that in your question you are abusing notations big time and that in the end these abuses are coming back to bite you.

Comment: I dont think you can write $x_i+y_i$... anyway Im not an expert (far less) on probability theory. Maybe you want to ask if $$\Pr[Z=z_i,Y=y_i]=\Pr[X=x_i,Y=y_i]$$ for $Z:=X+Y$ and $z_i=x_i+y_i$?

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for your comment. Yes, Actually the original statement is written as Z=X+Y, but as it simplified further $Z$ is not used.  I did not know using $Z$ makes a big difference. You mean if I wrote it as $Pr[Z=z_i, Y = y_i ] = Pr[X=x_i,Y=y_i]$, it is true?

Comment: @Crimson Idk if it true or not... just that the notation proposed seems more clear to me, at least more explicit. When you write $x_i+y_i$ you are implicitly defining a quantity $z_i=x_i+y_i$ more like some fixed quantities $x_i$ and $y_i$.

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for your time. I will rewrite the question, hopefully it will be more clear.

Comment: sorry, I had a terrible mistake in the answer I had written!!! But I fixed it

Comment: @ Masacroso Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second case I know that $$\Pr[X+Y=z|X=x]=\Pr[x+Y=z|X=x]=\Pr[Y=z-x|X=x]=\Pr[Y=y|X=x]$$

because by assumption $z=x+y$.

For the first case we can write, using the definition of conditional probability $$\begin{align}\Pr[X+Y=z, Y=y]&=\Pr[X+Y=z|Y=y]\Pr[Y=y]\\&=\Pr[X=z-y|Y=y]\Pr[Y=y]\\&=\Pr[X=x|Y=y]\Pr[Y=y]\\&=\Pr[X=x,Y=y]\end{align}$$

Thus both equalities holds.